# Symbolic gloabal variables in angr

Tags: angr

I am learning angr and for that I wrote a code containing two global variables.

```
char pwd[8];
char flag[16];
int main()
{
        printf("\n\nEnter your password and the flag: ");
        validator();
        return 0;
}
void validator()
{ 
        scanf("%s %s",pwd,flag);
        printf("\nThank You\n");//want to start the symbolic execution from here
        cipher_function();//works on pwd
        shuffle_function();//works on flag
        ...
       }
```

[image]

and here is the solution script:

```
 project = angr.Project(path_to_binary)

  start_address = 0x004011BB  
  initial_state = project.factory.blank_state(addr=start_address)
 
  initial_state.regs.rbp = initial_state.regs.rsp
  initial_state.regs.rdx = 0x00404080
  initial_state.regs.rsi = 0x00404070
 
  pwd = claripy.BVS('pwd', 8*8)
  flag = claripy.BVS('flag',16*8)

  initial_state.memory.store(0x00404070, pwd)
  initial_state.memory.store(0x00404080, flag)

  simulation = project.factory.simgr(initial_state)
```

Finally, the angr output is:

```
WARNING | 2021-03-02 08:11:19,750 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | The program is accessing memory or registers with an unspecified value. This could indicate unwanted behavior.
WARNING | 2021-03-02 08:11:19,750 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | angr will cope with this by generating an unconstrained symbolic variable and continuing. You can resolve this by:
WARNING | 2021-03-02 08:11:19,750 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 1) setting a value to the initial state
WARNING | 2021-03-02 08:11:19,750 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 2) adding the state option ZERO_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to make unknown regions hold null
WARNING | 2021-03-02 08:11:19,750 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 3) adding the state option SYMBOL_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to suppress these messages.
WARNING | 2021-03-02 08:11:19,750 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | Filling register cc_ndep with 8 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x40125e (cipher_function+0x2d in out2 (0x40125e))
```

can anyone please take a look and help me find what I am doing wrong.
Thank you

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? In the screenshot, what you have in your code as `start_address` is not, in fact, a valid instruction address. Notice that it ends in a `6`, whereas in the screenshot, valid last nibbles are `3` and `A`.

Comment: Thank you for the head up and sorry for the inconsistency in the code and screenshot. However, This is not the source of the issue, as I run it several time and got the same result.

Comment: I wrote my own symbolic execution framework, but have never used angr. That said, its output is telling to me. The final line indicates that the instruction at `0x40125e` tried to read from memory that had not previously been initialized. Figure out which function/line of code that is and see if it's accessing something like another global variable. Alternatively, hopefully it has a more verbose output method -- instruction by instruction -- that can give you clues about what it's trying to read, and why it's trying to read it.

Comment: I wrote a tool/angr plugin to help with debugging in such cases: https://github.com/fmagin/angr-cli
With this you should be able to easily find out at what point this happens and what is being read and then decide if this is even an issue.