# Why the global string varable exploitation using angr doesn't work?

Tags: python, strings, angr

To learn the angr module, I have made a simple C code like follows.

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char input[6];

int main(void)
{
    scanf("%s", input);

    if(strcmp(input, "hello")==0)
    {
        puts("Correct!");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Incorrect!");
    }
}
```

I complied this using gcc. and I disassemble it using gdb.

test disassemble code

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08049176 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x08049177 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x08049179 <+3>:     push   0x804c01c
   0x0804917e <+8>:     push   0x804a008
   0x08049183 <+13>:    call   0x8049060 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
   0x08049188 <+18>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x0804918b <+21>:    push   0x804a00b
   0x08049190 <+26>:    push   0x804c01c
   0x08049195 <+31>:    call   0x8049030 <strcmp@plt>
   0x0804919a <+36>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x0804919d <+39>:    test   eax,eax
   0x0804919f <+41>:    jne    0x80491b0 <main+58>
   0x080491a1 <+43>:    push   0x804a011
   0x080491a6 <+48>:    call   0x8049050 <puts@plt>
   0x080491ab <+53>:    add    esp,0x4
   0x080491ae <+56>:    jmp    0x80491bd <main+71>
   0x080491b0 <+58>:    push   0x804a01a
   0x080491b5 <+63>:    call   0x8049050 <puts@plt>
   0x080491ba <+68>:    add    esp,0x4
   0x080491bd <+71>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x080491c2 <+76>:    leave
   0x080491c3 <+77>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

and I make the exploit code using angr.
test.py

```
mport angr
import claripy

p=angr.Project('./test', auto_load_libs=True)

initial_state=p.factory.blank_state(addr=0x8049176)

password=claripy.BVS('password', 8*5)

password_addr=0x804c01c
initial_state.memory.store(password_addr, password)

sm=p.factory.simulation_manager(initial_state)

sm.explore(find=0x8049196, avoid=0x80491b5)

print(sm.found)

if sm.found:
    sol_state=sm.found[0]
    print(sol_state.solver.eval(password, cast_to=bytes))
```

When I excute this exploit code, it doesn't work!
output:

```
WARNING  | 2023-02-20 04:18:53,914 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | The program is accessing register with an unspecified value. This could indicate unwanted behavior.
WARNING  | 2023-02-20 04:18:53,914 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | angr will cope with this by generating an unconstrained symbolic variable and continuing. You can resolve this by:
WARNING  | 2023-02-20 04:18:53,914 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 1) setting a value to the initial state
WARNING  | 2023-02-20 04:18:53,915 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 2) adding the state option ZERO_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to make unknown regions hold null
WARNING  | 2023-02-20 04:18:53,915 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | 3) adding the state option SYMBOL_FILL_UNCONSTRAINED_{MEMORY,REGISTERS}, to suppress these messages.
WARNING  | 2023-02-20 04:18:53,915 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | Filling register ebp with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x8049176 (main+0x0 in test (0x8049176))
WARNING  | 2023-02-20 04:18:54,608 | angr.storage.memory_mixins.default_filler_mixin | Filling memory at 0x7fff0000 with 4 unconstrained bytes referenced from 0x80491c3 (main+0x4d in test (0x80491c3))
WARNING  | 2023-02-20 04:18:55,018 | angr.engines.successors | Exit state has over 256 possible solutions. Likely unconstrained; skipping. <BV32 mem_7fff0000_16_32{UNINITIALIZED}>
[]
```

What happend? I have searched on the Internet, I can't find the answer.
Here is a [similar question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/symbolic-gloabal-variables-in-angr), but it's not clear.

Comment: I don't know angr but I'd guess it doesn't know it needs to be looking for "Correct" not "Incorrect". How does your test.py identify that? (or is that one of the hex addresses?)

Comment: Why is your find address not an instruction boundary? It could be 0x080491a6